# Get content of local Visualforce Page from managed package code

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, getcontentaspdf

I have **Manage Package**, where is some logic which sends **Emails** with `EmailFileAttachment` ( using Visualforce page rendered as PDF ) to Customers.
I want to add possibility to users to **use theirs Custom Visualforce Page** when sending emails.

I added **Custom Setting** for it,
Where a user can enter the **Visualforce Page Name** and if this Name is set I use it.

**-------Issue-------**
When I set there a `Visualforce Page` which **is not from my Managed Package** I get the error :

*An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 1687133430-16791 (-553401195)*

This error throws on next line :

```code
Blob receiptAttBody = myVisualforcePageRef.getContentAsPDF();
```

The main logic looks like that :

```code
PageReference myVisualforcePageRef = new PageReference('/apex/'+ myVisualforcePageName); // this line works
myVisualforcePageRef.getParameters().put('id',recordId); // I tried to remove this line but it did not help
Blob receiptAttBody = myVisualforcePageRef.getContentAsPDF(); // error caused by this line
```

When I set there a `Visualforce Page` **from the managed package** it works ok.

However when I set there any page **outside the package** it throws the error!

I tried to add **the simplest page** without any logic and it still does not work.

Maybe there is any **limitation** on using `Visualforce Pages` ( which is **outside** of Managed Package ) **inside** in managed package code ?

I saw this question [Accessing a external VF page from managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/accessing-a-external-vf-page-from-managed-package) , However it did not help me.

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: What I can say is that we do almost exactly the same as you here in our managed package and it works fine as long as the external VF page is `renderAs="pdf"`, uses the appropriate `standardController` (for us our custom object) and has the required `extensions` with both `showHeader` and `sidebar` set `false`. I don't know if all these properties have to be set for the page, but these certainly work (even when the controller extensions are only `public` rather than `global` I believe).

Comment: @PhilW thank for your answer, I will try it

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, you have to prefix your unmanaged page reference with the default namespace don't you? e.g. `PageReference myVisualforcePageRef = new PageReference('/apex/c__'+ myVisualforcePageName);`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Adding to @PhilHawthorn's comment. The `c__` prefix for a Visualforce page in the subscriber org is covered in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25864/102

Comment: I will be interested to see if that does the trick. For us, we have never needed to add "c__" AFAIK to allow the managed code to render the subscriber org VF page.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Thank you so much,
I added the prefix and it did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering an unmanaged page from within a Managed Package requires that you specify the default namespace within the page url. I would imagine that this is because by default, the platform is trying to resolve the page from the managed namespace.

So:

`PageReference myVisualforcePageRef = new PageReference('/apex/' + myVisualforcePageName);`

Becomes:

`PageReference myVisualforcePageRef = new PageReference('/apex/c__' + myVisualforcePageName);`

Comment: Thank you so much, it did resolve the issue.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder why we didn't need to use "c__" (I haven't looked at this in a very long time, so perhaps something changed or I simply missed that this was done). Anyway, great to know!

Comment: Maybe different circumstances then @PhilW because we had to do this way back in a package I built in 2012 for emailing invoices